# how to run current service in docker-compose by parameter from .env?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file where I added creating web app and db (postgres). I need have a possibility switching from one database to another. How to create container by parameter $DB_TYPE (from .env file) in docker-compose file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used profiles https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/. It solved my problem.